# GoJs fill background the center circle

Tags: javascript, html, gojs

I just want to paint the center circle. How can I do this? I shared follows example project.

http://canturkgames.com/gojsexample

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the **Diagram** *after* the page and the diagram's HTML DIV element have been laid out, *and* did you set **Diagram.initialContentAlignment** to `go.Spot.Center`?